# Adjective that describes a person avoiding talk about mildly disgusting topics

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective that describes a person avoiding talk about mildly disgusting topics e.g. excrements or vomit?

An example sentence is: "He was so [word] that, when a passenger said he was about to throw up, he put on a blank expression and pretended he had business outside the cabin.".

As someone pointed out in a comment, "delicate" is somewhat related, yet, I feel does not capture the meaning entirely.

Comment: Erm..... _delicate_ ?

Comment: Hm, I guess that is pretty close. I wonder if there's something even closer.

Comment: ...maybe _squeamish_ ...I won't post a formal answer until this Q abides with  site standards.

Comment: You mean they're tip-toeing around the topic?

Comment: @Slavic You need to add an example sentence (show where/how you would use the word in a sentence. Something like this: He grimaced when they started talking about bowel movements, because he was _. Idk) And you need to show the research you did in an effort to figure out the answer yourself before posting (links to sites that didn’t have what you wanted, words you thought of using but whose definitions don’t fit, etc.)

Comment: repulsed - cause (someone) to feel intense distaste and aversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon why he was avoiding the subject --

If he was sickened by the discussion:

[**Squeamish**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squeamish)

> : easily nauseated : QUEASY
>
> b : affected with nausea
>
> 2a : excessively fastidious or scrupulous in conduct or belief
>
> b : easily offended or disgusted

[**Genteel**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genteel) if he was too polite to discuss such base matters.

> c: elegant or graceful in manner, appearance, or shape:
> *the genteel manners of an old southern gentleman*
>
> d: free from vulgarity or rudeness : POLITE